# Regular expression - removing brackets and what is inside if they follow a certain structure

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a text example like

> `Hello my car is [tue mar 31 2020 - antoni mark ] [nissan]`

I want to remove the square brackets and what is inside it if it has the structure `"tue mar 31 2020 - antoni mark"`.

So the text_filtered should look like `"Hello my car is [nissan]"` I am trying to use this pattern
`"\[.*?\]"`, but it removes all square brackets.

Any idea on how to modify the pattern?

Comment: Would it work to remove all bracketed containing at least one space? E.g. [`\[(?!\S*\])[^\]\[]*\]`](https://regex101.com/r/D4zGk5/1)

Answer (score 1):

This matches a space then square brackets containing a date in your format then a dash then non-square brackets:

```
" \[\w{3} \w{3} \d\d? \d{4} - [^]]+]"
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/hchzDY0MppBoD0).

Matching the leading space will prevent the result after replacing with blank from containing double spaces.